# How can I move to another UIViewController programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios5

I'm using a storyboard with Xcode 4.3.3

I want to move to one of two `UIViewControllers` depending on an `if` condition result.
Is there any way to do that because I tried some code but it's not working and not showing an error.

for ex:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"You identifier" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down control and drag from your initial view controller to each destination, one at a time.  Each time select the type of segue that you want to use (a push segue will not work unless the initial controller is embedded in a UINavigationController).  Then click the each segue, open the attributes inspector, and give each a unique name.  Then do something like

```
if (condition) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue1" sender:self];
}

else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue2" sender:self];
}
```